# Delete multiple rows of data from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I need help of making a SQL query, when I delete the main category it should delete all the data of my subcategory and all the products related to that subcategory. Basically deleting data from 3 tables.

Can it be done in one query?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first

Comment: You need to look into cascading delete foreign key definitions.

Comment: This will be **highly dependent** on what actual, concrete RDBMS you're using ..... please add a relevant tag to make this clear!

Answer (score 0):

Cant give you code sample without a Database reference. But if all the tables have the same Primary key you can try using `INNER JOIN`.

```
DELETE table1, table2, table3
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.key = table1.key
INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.key = table1.key
WHERE table1.key = value;
```

key value should be common accross all tables. Something like a "ID".

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. You should mention for which DBMS your solution work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving it via Sql, you could use foreign keys with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` setting enabled.

If you database type/version supports it.
F.e. [ANSI SQL:2003](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#CASCADE), [MySSQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/), [Oracle](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-foreign-key/), [MS SQL Server](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php), [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

That way, when you delete from the main table.  Then the records in the other table that reference to those deleted records, will automatically be deleted also.

For example in MS Sql Server:

```
ALTER TABLE SubCategory
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SubCategory_MainCategoryID_Cascade
FOREIGN KEY (MainCategoryID)
REFERENCES MainCategory(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Products
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Products_SubCategoryID_Cascade
FOREIGN KEY (SubCategoryID)
REFERENCES SubCategory(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

It's a way to automatically maintain the referential integrity between them.

After that a delete from the MainCategory table will delete the related records from the SubCategory table.  And also the Products that are related to the deleted SubCategory records.

And [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=4ef7211539fe1e42500f2df5f8b2059d) is a *db<>fiddle* example for SQLite to demonstrate.

*P.S. Personally I would prefere an `ON DELETE SET NULL` or an `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT n`, or even using triggers.  Sure, that would require an extra cleanup of the unreferenced records afterwards, f.e. via a scheduled script.  But it just feels less detrimental. Because then it's easier to fix when someone accidently deleted a MainCategory that shouldn't have been deleted.*